# $\mathbf{A}^1$- contractibility

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, motives, motivic-cohomology

Suppose $U$ is an $\mathbf{A}^1$-contractible smooth scheme over a field $k$, that is, it is isomorphic to a point in the $\mathbf{A}^1$-homotopy category of smooth schemes over $k$.

Does motivic cohomology of $U$ satisfy some cohomological vanishing property?

That is, $H^{i}_{\mathcal{M}}(U,\mathbf{Z}(n)) = 0$ for what $(i,n)$?

Comment: Motivic cohomology depends only on the motivic homotopy type, so the motivic cohomology of U is equal to that of a point

Comment: @DenisNardin Where could I find a reference where $H^i_{\mathcal{M}}(\text{Spec}(k),\mathbf{Z}(n))$ is treated? Is it computed for every $k$? Probably very specific fields, so far.

Comment: Page 12 of http://www.math.ias.edu/vladimir/files/Seatle_lectures_notes_by_Weibel_published.pdf has a few criteria, but I don't know what has been improved since then. These are difficult questions, and Beilinson-Soule Vanishing is not even known for fields(apparently the case of fields implies it for all regular schemes, see http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.456.6145&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Computing the motivic cohomology of fields is kind of a big open problem... There are a few 'obvious' bounds and then everything else is some big conjecture. I suggest to look into work on the Bloch-Kato conjecture and hunt your way from there. I think motivic cohomology has been computed for finite fields (away from the characteristic) and maybe $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, plus some partial results for number and function fields ([this](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~dan/KtheoryHandbook-for-authors-only/Weibel/weibel6.pdf) survey by Weibel could be a good starting point).

Comment: I suggest you to "split the problem" into two parts. Torsion motivic cohomology is isomorphic to the corresponding Galois one, whereas rational motivic cohomology groups give K-theory and so are very difficult to compute.